# Gravity Forms - Radio buttons with individual descriptions

Tags: radio-button, gravity-forms-plugin

I have some radio buttons that need text descriptions for each choice so users know what they are choosing.

I would like to add an input field in the radio buttons options for each radio button option that can accept HTML. This then needs to be displayed within each radio list item. I've tried simply adding the details to a HTML area underneath, but this is not suitable for mobile screens as the details are independant from the radio choices and so do not appear under each radio when the screen is re-sized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered including the description inside the Radio Button label? If you configure each choice label like so:

`<div><span>First Choice</span><span>And this is the description.</div>`

You could style it with the following CSS:

```
.ginput_container_radio input {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.ginput_container_radio label span {
    display: block;
}

.ginput_container_radio label span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0.6;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

And it'd look something like this:

[image: Screenshot of Radio Button Field]

Comment: I wasn't even aware that the label field accepts HTML! Thank you very much for this, it is of course exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: David, this doesn't seem to work with Gravity Form's 'Option' field type. Do you know if there is a way to overcome this? I'm calculating pricing on options so I can't go back to using a standard radio field...